# Insert images in two columns in table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 4 columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SaveFiles
(
    FileID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Image1 VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Image2 VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
)
```

I am trying to insert images into `image1` and `image2` columns.

I am able to insert only one image in `image1` column, I tried to insert `image2` column as well at a time in a table. I have used below query to insert image in `image1`, but my target is to insert `image2` as well.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SaveFiles] ([FileID], Name, Files)
    SELECT  
        1, 'Home Page 2', 
        BulkColumn 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\LOGOS\Home Page.png', SINGLE_BLOB) image;
```

I tried to insert two columns as below. But am not able to insert, please help me to insert 4 columns, 1 `int`, 2 `nvarchar`, `VARBINARY`, `VARBINARY` into table.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SaveFiles] ([FileID], Name, Files)
    SELECT  
        1, 'Home Page 2', 
        BulkColumn 
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\LOGOS\Home Page.png', SINGLE_BLOB) image,
        BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\LOGOS\Home Page.png', SINGLE_BLOB) image;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to insert same image in 2 columns?

Comment: Thanks for reply,Am trying to insert two different images in two different columns, from above lines execute the same, getting below error. " Line 5 & 6: A correlation name must be specified for the bulk rowset in the from clause." Please suggest me for next step. Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to insert same image in 2 columns then you can try this query. You just need to use OPENROWSET once.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SaveFiles] ([FileID], Name, Image1, Image2) 
SELECT 
  1, 
  'Home Page 2', 
  image.BulkColumn ,
  image.BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\LOGOS\Home Page.png', SINGLE_BLOB) image
```

If you are trying to insert 2 different images then, use OPENROWSET twice as below.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SaveFiles] ([FileID], Name, Image1, Image2) 
    SELECT 
      1, 
      'Home Page 2', 
      (Select BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\LOGOS\Home Page1.png', SINGLE_BLOB) as img1) ,
      (Select BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\LOGOS\Home Page2.png', SINGLE_BLOB)  as img2)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,Am trying to insert two different images in two different columns, from above lines, when I tried to execute the same, getting below error.   " Line 5 & 6:  A correlation name must be specified for the bulk rowset in the from clause."  Please suggest me for next step.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Am trying to insert two different images in two different columns, from above lines, when I tried to execute the same, getting below error. " Line 5 & 6: A correlation name must be specified for the bulk rowset in the from clause." Please suggest me for next step. – Eric